# Python regex ignore punctuation when using re.sub

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Let's say I want to convert the word **center** to **centre**, **theater** to **theatre**, etc. In order to do so, I have written a regex like the one below:

```
s = "center ce..nnnnnnnnteeeerrrr mmmmeeeeet.eeerrr liiiiIIiter l1t3r"
regex = re.compile(r'(?:((?:(?:[l1]+\W*[i!1]+|m+\W*[e3]+|c+\W*[e3]+\W*n+)\W*t+|t+\W*h+\W*[e3]+\W*a+\W*t+|m+\W*a+\W*n+\W*[e3]+\W*u+\W*v+)\W*)([e3]+)(\W*)(r+))', re.I)
print(regex.sub(r'\1\4\3\2',s)
#prints "centre ce..nnnnnnnntrrrreeee mmmmeeeeet.rrreee liiiiIIitre l1tr3"
```

In order to account for loopholes like **c.e.nn.ttteee,/rr** (basically repeated characters and added punctuation), I have been forced to add `\W*` between each character.

However, people are still able to use strings like `c.c.e.e.n.n.t.t.e.e.r.r`, which don't match as there is punctuation between each letter, not just different letters.

I was wondering whether there is a smarter method of doing this, where I can use `re.sub` without removing whitespace/punctuation but nonetheless have it match.

Comment: What's hard for me to understand is that the use case you presented `center to centre, theater to theatre` is FAR from `ce..nnnnnnnnteeeerrrr to centre` :P Sounds like you might as well just measure the number of each character and do a 'close enough' match using SequenceMatcher library

Comment: if the requirement is **"Let's say I want to convert the word center to centre, theater to theatre, etc"** can we simply change words that ends with `re` to `er`? like so: `(e)(r)\b` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DG6VIR/1)

Comment: @Matt.G Not all words that end with er are supposed to be converted. Pretty stupid, I know :p

Comment: One way to do this could be to replace all `<char>+\W*` with `(?:<char>\W*)+` but honestly even I think that is too explosive.

Comment: how do we know which ones to find and replace? also why is lit3r changed to litr3. and what should happen to centeeerr and centeerrr?

Comment: centeeerr would become centrreee, as the `r` blocks and the `e` blocks are switched. Lit3r is changed because `3` is counted as `e`

Comment: How abt [`(e+|3+)([^e3])*(r+)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/DG6VIR/2)

Comment: That matches all words ending with er, which is not what i want. For example, better should not become "bettre"

Comment: I'm not sure how to acheive that without knowing the list of words that can be changed..

Comment: I'm just asking for a way to match and replace while ignoring punctuation, but not removing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169823/discussion-between-unsignedbyte-and-matt-g).